# Trying to understand Big-oh notation

Tags: big-o

Hi I would really appreciate some help with Big-O notation. I have an exam in it tomorrow and while I can define what f(x) is O(g(x)) is, I can't say I thoroughly understand it.

The following question ALWAYS comes up on the exam and I really need to try and figure it out, the first part seems easy (I think) Do you just pick a value for n, compute them all on a claculator and put them in order? This seems to easy though so I'm not sure. I'm finding it very hard to find examples online.

> From lowest to highest, what is the
> correct order of the complexities
> O(n2), O(log2 n), O(1), O(2n), O(n!),
> O(n log2 n)?
>
> What is the
> worst-case computational-complexity of
> the Binary Search algorithm on an
> ordered list of length n = 2k?

Comment: "Do you just pick a value for n, compute them all on a claculator and put them in order?" Nope, because O(2n) == O(n).

Comment: @Ben Hocking Nope because of infinitesimal calculus actually :)

Comment: By `O(n2)`, do you mean `O(n-to-the-power-of-2)`?

Answer (score 3):

[That guy should help you](http://books.google.com/books?id=NLngYyWFl_YC&lpg=PP1&dq=cormen&pg=PA41#v=onepage&q&f=false).

> From lowest to highest, what is the
>   correct order of the complexities
>   O(n2), O(log2 n), O(1), O(2n), O(n!),
>   O(n log2 n)?

The order is same as if you compare their limit at infinity. like `lim(a/b)`, if it is 1, then they are same, inf. or 0 means one of them is faster.

> What is the worst-case
>   computational-complexity of the Binary
>   Search algorithm on an ordered list of
>   length n = 2k?

1. Find binary search best/worst Big-O.
2. Find linked list access by index best/worst Big-O.
3. Make conclusions.

Answer (score 2):

Hey there. Big-O notation is tough to figure out if you don't really understand what the "**n**" means. You've already seen people talking about how O(**n**) == O(**2n**), so I'll try to explain exactly why that is.

When we describe an algorithm as having "order-**n** space complexity", we mean that the size of the storage space used by the algorithm gets larger with a linear relationship to the size of the problem that it's working on (referred to as **n**.) If we have an algorithm that, say, sorted an array, and in order to do that sort operation the largest thing we did in memory was to create an exact copy of that array, we'd say that had "order-**n** space complexity" because as the size of the array (call it **n** elements) got larger, the algorithm would take up more space in order to match the input of the array. Hence, the algorithm uses "O(**n**)" space in memory.

Why does O(**2n**) = O(**n**)? Because when we talk in terms of O(**n**), we're only concerned with the behavior of the algorithm as **n** gets as large as it could possibly be. If **n** was to become infinite, the O(**2n**) algorithm would take up two times infinity spaces of memory, and the O(**n**) algorithm would take up one times infinity spaces of memory. Since two times infinity is just infinity, both algorithms are considered to take up a similar-enough amount of room to be both called O(**n**) algorithms.

You're probably thinking to yourself "An algorithm that takes up twice as much space as another algorithm is still relatively inefficient. Why are they referred to using the same notation when one is much more efficient?" Because the gain in efficiency for arbitrarily large **n** when going from O(**2n**) to O(**n**) is absolutely dwarfed by the gain in efficiency for arbitrarily large **n** when going from O(**n^2**) to O(**500n**). When **n** is 10, **n^2** is 10 times 10 or 100, and **500n** is 500 times 10, or 5000. But we're interested in **n** as **n** becomes as large as possible. They cross over and become equal for an **n** of 500, but once more, we're not even interested in an **n** as small as 500. When **n** is 1000, **n^2** is one MILLION while **500n** is a "mere" half million. When **n** is one million, **n^2** is one thousand billion - 1,000,000,000,000 - while **500n** looks on in awe with the simplicity of it's five-hundred-million - 500,000,000 - points of complexity. And once more, we can keep making **n** larger, because when using O(**n**) logic, we're only concerned with the largest possible **n**.

(You may argue that when **n** reaches infinity, **n^2** is infinity times infinity, while **500n** is five hundred times infinity, and didn't you just say that anything times infinity is infinity? That doesn't actually work for infinity times infinity. I think. It just doesn't. Can a mathematician back me up on this?)

This gives us the weirdly counterintuitive result where O(**Seventy-five hundred billion spillion kajillion n**) is considered an improvement on O(**n * log n**). Due to the fact that we're working with arbitrarily large "**n**", all that matters is how many times and where **n** appears in the O(). The rules of thumb mentioned in Julia Hayward's post will help you out, but here's some additional information to give you a hand.

One, because n gets as big as possible, O(**n^2+61n+1682**) = O(**n^2**), because the **n^2** contributes so much more than the **61n** as **n** gets arbitrarily large that the **61n** is simply ignored, and the **61n** term already dominates the **1682** term. If you see addition inside a O(), only concern yourself with the **n** with the highest degree.

Two, O(**log10n**) = O(**log**(any number)**n**), because for any base **b**, log10(**x**) = log_**b**(**x**)/log_**b**(10). Hence, O(**log10n**) = O(**log_b(x) * 1/(log_b(10)**). That 1/log_b(10) figure is a constant, which we've already shown drop out of O(**n**) notation.

Comment: Its not about "space in memory".  Its about the time required to execute the function for increasing large values of n.

Comment: @JK: Big-O notation can be used for space or time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Very loosely, you could imagine picking extremely large values of n, and calculating them. Might exceed your calculator's range for large factorials, though.

If the definition isn't clear, a more intuitive description is that "higher order" means "grows faster than, as n grows". Some rules of thumb:

- O(n^a) is a higher order than O(n^b) if a > b.
- log(n) grows more slowly than any positive power of n
- exp(n) grows more quickly than any power of n
- n! grows more quickly than exp(kn)

Oh, and as far as complexity goes, ignore the constant multipliers.

That's enough to deduce that the correct order is O(1), O(log n), O(2n) = O(n), O(n log n), O(n^2), O(n!)

Answer (score 1):

For big-O complexities, the rule is that if two things vary only by constant factors, then they are the same. If one grows faster than another ignoring constant factors, then it is bigger.

So O(2n) and O(n) are the same -- they only vary by a constant factor (2). One way to think about it is to just drop the constants, since they don't impact the complexity.

The other problem with picking n and using a calculator is that it will give you the wrong answer for certain n. Big O is a measure of how fast something grows as n increases, but at any given n the complexities might not be in the right order. For instance, at n=2, n^2 is 4 and n! is 2, but n! grows quite a bit faster than n^2.

It's important to get that right, because for running times with multiple terms, you can drop the lesser terms -- ie, if O(f(n)) is 3n^2+2n+5, you can drop the 5 (constant), drop the 2n (3n^2 grows faster), then drop the 3 (constant factor) to get O(n^2)... but if you don't know that n^2 is bigger, you won't get the right answer.

In practice, you can just know that n is linear, log(n) grows more slowly than linear, n^a > n^b if a>b, 2^n is faster than any n^a, and n! is even faster than that. (Hint: try to avoid algorithms that have n in the exponent, and especially avoid ones that are n!.)

For the second part of your question, what happens with a binary search in the worst case? At each step, you cut the space in half until eventually you find your item (or run out of places to look). That is log2(2k). A search where you just walk through the list to find your item would take n steps. And we know from the first part that O(log(n)) < O(n), which is why binary search is faster than just a linear search.

Good luck with the exam!

Answer (score 0):

In easy to understand terms the Big-O notation defines how quickly a particular function grows. Although it has its roots in pure mathematics its most popular application is the analysis of algorithms which can be analyzed on the basis of input size to determine the approximate number of operations that must be performed.

The benefit of using the notation is that you can categorize function growth rates by their complexity. Many different functions (an infinite number really) could all be expressed with the same complexity using this notation. For example, `n+5`, `2*n`, and `4*n + 1/n` all have `O(n)` complexity because the function `g(n)=n` **most simply** represents how these functions grow.

I put an emphasis on *most simply* because the focus of the notation is on the dominating term of the function. For example, `O(2*n + 5) = O(2*n) = O(n)` because `n` is the dominating term in the growth. This is because the notation assumes that `n` goes to infinity which causes the remaining terms to play less of a role in the growth rate. And, by convention, any constants or multiplicatives are omitted.

Read [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) and [Time complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) for more a more in depth overview.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~cs1102s/assignments/) and look up for solutions here is first one.

[image]